# Not able so send mails to custom domains

Tags: email, domain

I have setup the MX (Mail Exchanger) in GoDaddy appropriately as shown below to work with gmail for my www.thecloudavenue.com domain account.

[image]

But when when someone sends an email to xyz@thecloudavenue.com it bounces and they get the below response. But, I am able to send mails from xyz@thecloudavenue.com to others.

> Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 #5.1.0 Address rejected. (state 13).

I raised a ticked with GoDaddy and they asked me contact Google support as below.

> In reviewing your account, we see that you have correctly updated your domain's DNS to point to Google's mail servers. If you continue having issues with your email, please review this issue with Google support. I hope this clarifies the issue for you.

What could be the reason for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to e-mail I sent to the address you pointed I got the following delivery report:

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> ```
>  xyz@thecloudavenue.com
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend
>   contacting the other email provider for further information about the
>   cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550
>   550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist.
>   Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for
>   typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596
>   f7si18257825obd.136 (state 13).

The e-mail was sent from account hosted at Google Mail. That clearly indicates that the problem is with configuration of your mail service in Google. You should contact Google to resolve the problem

Comment: Thanx - I did complete the process in Google and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Serge and GoDaddy. The problem is somewhere in your configuration of Google Apps. It’s been a while since I set up a Google Apps account, but I seem to remember certain steps had to be followed before email could be enabled.

Have you completed all the initial configuration steps? For example, adding a Google specified CNAME or TXT record to your domain to verify ownership?